# Loop through elements and animate one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bar chart I'm trying to create and I want to animate each bar into view...

I've marked up my bar chart using data-height attributes like so...

```
<ul class="chart">
  <li><div class="top" data-height="48"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="52"></div></li>
  <li><div class="top" data-height="45"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div></li>
  <li><div class="top" data-height="45"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div></li>
  <li><div class="top" data-height="42"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="58"></div></li>
  <li><div class="top" data-height="45"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div></li>
  <li><div class="top" data-height="47"></div><div class="bottom" data-height="53"></div></li>
</ul>
```

And my js is...

```
$('.top, .bottom').animate({
   height : $(this).data("data-height") 
}, 1000);
```

Only I'm not getting anything, can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is `.data("height")` not `.data("data-height")`
2. You need to set a timeout around if you like to run each after each.

```js
$('li').each(function(i) {
    setTimeout(function(top, bottom) {
        top.animate({
            height: top.data("height") 
        }, 1000);

        bottom.animate({
            height: bottom.data("height") 
        }, 1000);
    }, i * 1000, $(".top", this), $(".bottom", this));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
li div {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="chart">
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="48"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="52"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="45"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="45"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Another way, don't use `animate`, use `css transitions`. ;)

```js
$("ul.chart li").each(function(i) {
    var li = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.top, .bottom', li).height(function() {
            return $(this).data("height");
        });
    }, i * 1000);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
li div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: height 1s;
  -moz-transition: height 1s;
  transition: height 1s;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="chart">
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="48"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="52"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="45"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="top" data-height="45"></div>
    <div class="bottom" data-height="55"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming `this` points to each bar in turn; it doesn't, as there's no change of context as would be the case with an `each` callback (loop), for example. So:

```
$('.top, .bottom').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
       height : $(this).data("data-height") 
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I'm still getting nothing @Utkanos, heres my codepen... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yaOLvQ

Comment: because function is not closed @Liam

Comment: You writed animation duration in each parameter.

Comment: @Liam instead of `$(this).data("data-height")` you should write `$(this).data("height") `

Comment: @liam - you are using .data("data-height") which is wrong and so it couldn't find the attribute "data-data-height". 
it should be either .data("height") or .attr("data-height")

Answer (score 0):

To animate through the each elements, you have to process it using loop. only 'this' is not enough for this.

```
$('.top, .bottom').each(function(){
 $(this).animate({
   height : $(this).data("height") 
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It appears someone doesn't agree with jQuery based solutions (considering Utkanos's answer was downvoted too). But they're both viable solutions so I don't see any reason they should be downvoted.

Comment: But they both are wrong too. `data("data-height")` will never work.

Comment: @eisbehr ohh yeah, you are right. updated the answer .